# Get container element inside Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to initialize a chart with Highcharts: how can I obtain the `data('values')` of the element that Highcharts use as the container of the chart?

This is an example of the container

```
<div id="container" data-values="[...]">
```

And this an example of the code, that doesn't work.

```
$('#container').highcharts({

   ...

   series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Votes',
      data: $(this).data('values')
   }]
});
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with $(this) reference, so try to use $('#container'), and will work. See the example:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.highcharts({
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: $container.data('values')
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77bx2q3t/

Comment: thanks but quite often i have no id, only class, like `<div class="chart"></div>`